# MS Access - Module - VBA - Compile Error : Expected Idenitifier - Table with Spaces in Name

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table that I am trying to write a module that will go in and add two columns to an existing table. I have a table that has existing spaces in the name and I get an error of Compile Error : Expected Identifier.

```
Private Sub AddColumn()
Dim curDatabase As Database
Dim [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE] As TableDef
Dim Yrs_of_Svc As Field
Dim Yrs_of_Svc_Cat As Field


' Get a reference to the current database
 Set curDatabase = CurrentDb

' Get a reference to a table named TestTable - NOTE: The table MUST exist
 Set [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE] = curDatabase.TableDefs("[Final LOS and PAPW TABLE]")

'define the fields using the CreateField method
' Syntax: .CreateField("FIELD NAME", TYPE, [Length])
' I used the predefined types already in Access
 Set Yrs_of_Svc = [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].CreateField("Yrs_of_Svc", dbDouble, 5)
 Set Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].CreateField("Yrs_of_Svc_Cat", dbText, 2)

 If Len(Offc_TRMN_DT) > 1 Then
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc = [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Offc_TRMN_DT - [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Offc_EMPLMT_DT
 Else
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc = [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].BSE_ISS_RGST_DT - [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Offc_EMPLMT_DT
 End If


 Select Case Yrs_of_Svc    ' Evaluate Number.

 Case 0 To 1.99
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = 1

 Case 2.01 To 2.99
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = 2

 Case 3.01 To 3.99
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = 3

 Case 4.01 To 4.99
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = 4

 Case Is > 5#
    [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE].Yrs_of_Svc_Cat = 5+

 End Select



 End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Robert

Comment: `Dim [Final LOS and PAPW TABLE] As TableDef` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name doesn't have to be the same as the table name, and in this case it definitely shouldn't because you cannot have spaces in a variable name.  The brackets do not have the same functionality in VBA as they do in SQL.  Use CamelCase (`FinalLosAndPapwTable`) or use underscores (`Final_LOS_and_PAPW_TABLE`) instead of spaces.

For more info on naming [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264773%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

It also looks like you're trying to assign values to `Yrs_of_Svc` and `Yrs_of_Svc_Cat` but those are `Field` objects so I don't think you can do that.  Reply if you receive more errors after fixing the variable names.